# ruby - how to get ssh prompt from remote server with "Net::SSH"

Tags: python, ruby, ssh

When we code with python,  **paramiko** can help us to get **prompt_list** which is in **custom_handler**. If ruby is the choice, how to get the prompt list with **Net::SSH** ?

---

Python Code as follow:

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import paramiko
from paramiko.py3compat import u
import base64
import hashlib
import termios
import tty

def custom_handler(title, instructions, prompt_list):
    n = prompt_list[0][0]
    m = hashlib.sha1()
    m.update('\x00' * 12)
    m.update(n + 'FGTAbc11*xy+Qqz27')
    m.update('\xA3\x88\xBA\x2E\x42\x4C\xB0\x4A\x53\x79\x30\xC1\x31\x07\xCC\x3F\xA1\x32\x90\x29\xA9\x81\x5B\x70')
    h = 'AK1' + base64.b64encode('\x00' * 12 + m.digest())
    return [h]


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ' <target-ip>'
        exit(-1)

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        client.connect(sys.argv[1], username='', allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException:
        pass

    trans = client.get_transport()
    try:
        trans.auth_password(username='Fortimanager_Access', password='', event=None, fallback=True)
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
        pass

    trans.auth_interactive(username='Fortimanager_Access', handler=custom_handler)
    chan = client.invoke_shell()

    oldtty = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby net-ssh calling bash script with interactive prompts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882776/ruby-net-ssh-calling-bash-script-with-interactive-prompts)

Comment: If an invalid credential, Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed will come. We need to get prompt string also when authentication fails